# Find max/min occurrence in integer array

Tags: c, arrays, frequency

I just finished writing an algorithm that finds values in an input integer array with max/min occurrences. My idea is to sort the array (all the occurrences are now in sequence) and use a `<value:occurrences>` pair to store for every value the number of occurrences correspondent.

It should be `O(nlogn)` complexity but I think that there are some constant multipliers. What can I do to improve performance?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "e7_8.h"

#define N 20
/*Structure for <value, frequencies_count> pair*/
typedef struct {
    int value;
    int freq;
} VAL_FREQ;


void  get_freq(int *v, int n, int *most_freq, int *less_freq) {

    int v_i, vf_i, current_value, current_freq;

    VAL_FREQ* sp = malloc(n*sizeof(VAL_FREQ));
    if(sp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    mergesort(v,n);

    vf_i = 0;
    current_value = v[0];
    current_freq = 1;
    for(v_i=1; v_i<n+1; v_i++) {
        if(v[v_i] == current_value) current_freq++;
        else{
            sp[vf_i].value = current_value;
            sp[vf_i++].freq = current_freq;
            current_value = v[v_i];
            current_freq = 1;
        }
    }
    /*Finding max,min frequency*/
    int i, max_freq_val, max_freq, min_freq_val, min_freq;

    max_freq = sp[0].freq;
    max_freq_val = sp[0].value;
    min_freq = sp[0].freq;
    min_freq_val = sp[0].value;
    for(i=1; i<vf_i; i++) {
        if(sp[i].freq > max_freq) {
            max_freq = sp[i].freq;
            max_freq_val = sp[i].value;
        }
        if(sp[i].freq < min_freq) {
            min_freq = sp[i].freq;
            min_freq_val = sp[i].value;
        }
    }

    *most_freq = max_freq_val;
    *less_freq = min_freq_val;

    free(sp);
}
```

Comment: Do you know the maximum value expected in input? And the minimum value? Is it negative?

Comment: No. It's only a didactic algorithm, no practical use.

Comment: Is `n` the size of your array? If so, you're indexing past the end of it in your first loop. Also, if you fix that, there's a chance you're not going to update the last `VAL_FREQ` structure correctly. Do away with the `current_value` and `current_freq` variables and update the structure members directly.

Comment: when you say "it" shold be O(nlogn) what's it? A sort and then a search for a single occurrence, all occurrences, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from the fact that your algorithm is already O(n*log(n)), as every step is O(n) apart the sorting which is O(n*log(n)). If it can be significantly improved depends on which kind of input you expect. **Edit:** Unless, and that appears to be the case, it is not part of the requirement having the values sorted (in any case by value, not by number of occurrences) at the end of the process, in which case do not miss Oli Charlesworth's answer.

There are 2 concept on the ground: the first is how many samples are you going to get (n); the second is "how concentrated" are their values, how narrow or wide is the range where these values can be distributed (w = MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE).

If n is smaller than w (so your values are sparse), than your approach is already optimal and has little space for improvement.

But if w is small and n is big, you have much to gain with the following method.

Let's say you know you cannot get any value less than MIN_VALUE, and no value more than MAX_VALUE. Then, you can use value as an index for an array where you collect your frequencies. In this way, you skip the sorting step (O(n*log(n)) ), and you compute your frequencies in O(n).

```
int buffer_frequencies[MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1];

//Now reset the array with some convenient function like memset

int* value_frequencies = buffer_frequencies;
value_frequencies -= MIN_VALUE; //Shift the beginning of the array, so that 
                                //you can use the value directly as the array index
//You are allowed to use negative indexes
for(v_i=0; v_i < n; v_i++) {
  value_frequencies[v[v_i]]++;
  }
```

Or even (possibly slight faster version of the for cycle, but usually a good compiler will already convert it in the most efficient version):

```
int* p_v = v;
int* end_p_v = v+n;
for(; p_v < end_p_v; p_v++) {
  value_frequencies[*p_v]++;
  }
```

Be careful that this method (both versions) is very delicate to the input values, i.e. you will break memory boundaries if you get a value beyond MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE

Then the second part of the algorithm:

```
//First cycle could be optimized, but it has no impact
int i = MIN_VALUE;
max_freq = value_frequencies[i];
max_freq_val = i;
min_freq = value_frequencies[i];
min_freq_val = i;
for(; i<MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    max_freq_val = (value_frequencies[i] > max_freq) ? i : max_freq_val;
    max_freq = (value_frequencies[i] > max_freq) ? value_frequencies[i] : max_freq;
    min_freq_val = (value_frequencies[i] < min_freq) ? i : min_freq_val;
    min_freq = (value_frequencies[i] < min_freq) ? value_frequencies[i] : min_freq;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FabioCarello Check the last edit, I had left one nasty error

Comment: A few bugs; you cannot do `value_frequencies += MIN_VALUE;` (and even if you could, it should be `-=`); upper limit of `if` should be `<`, not `<=`; the updates to `max_freq_val` and `min_freq_val` will never occur...

Answer (score 5):

Use a hash-table to implement a key-value map?  That should give you O(n) expected time.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* However, note that it's O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case.  This only occurs when all entries hash to the same bucket, and you effectively end up searching a linked-list for every iteration!  For decent hash-table implementation, the probability of this occurring is very low indeed.</sub>

Comment: Considering that the values to store are small (occupy little memory), a hash-table is point less. Value can be directly used as key without hash function.

Comment: @Antonio: Where is it stated that the values are "small"?  I'm not sure that's a good reason to downvote...

Comment: They are integers, not big structures.

Comment: @Antonio: Sure, but an `int` is typically 32-bit.  So whilst the counting sort you propose is O(n), it would require 4GB+ unless you have some constraints on the range.

Comment: That was highly underlined in my answer

Comment: @Antonio: Indeed.  The hash-table approach is more general (so not at all "pointless" ;) )

Comment: However, I now realize that having values sorted is NOT part of the requirement: therefore, I change my downvote to upvote. Can you do a small edit to allow me to do so? :) It says it's locked unless you edit it :)

Comment: @Antonio: I appreciate it!  Incidentally, I've converted my downvote on your answer now that you've fixed most/all of the bugs...

Comment: Can you add more detail about the worst case? I think your answer is getting intriguing now, and I am too tired to think about it myself :)