# Find n repeating numbers in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, hashtable

I have implemented the problem statement below using the hashtable library functions in C. Since I have never used standard library hashtable in C, my questions are:

1. Am I using the hashtable functions correctly (I believe getting output doesn't mean right usage)?
2. Is there any better way to achieve the solution for the given problem statement?

Problem statement: Find the n most frequent element in an array.

- 1 < N < 100000 [ Length of Array]
- -1000000 < n < 1000000 [ Array integers]

I have gone through some of the similar questions at SO - and in one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307097/find-max-min-occurrence-in-integer-array?rq=1) I do see the recommended approach being to use a hashtable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define REPEAT 3
#define BUFFERSIZE 10

void freqElement(int* arr, int len, int times);
int createHT(int* arr, int len);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 10, 2, 5, 2};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    ENTRY e;
    ENTRY *ep;

    hcreate(len);

    if (!createHT(arr, len))
    {
        printf(" error in entering data \n");
    }

    freqElement(arr, len, REPEAT);

    hdestroy();
    return 0;
}

int createHT(int* arr, int len)
{
    ENTRY e, *ep;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        snprintf(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "%d", arr[i]);
        e.key = buffer;
        e.data = (void *)1;

        ep = hsearch(e, FIND);
        if (ep)
        {
            ep->data = (void *)((int)ep->data + (int)e.data);
        }
        ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);
        if (ep == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "entry failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void freqElement(int* arr, int len, int times)
{
   ENTRY *ep, e;

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
       char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
       snprintf(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "%d", arr[i]);
       e.key = buffer;
       ep = hsearch(e, FIND);
       if(ep)
       {
           if((int)ep->data == times)
           {
               printf(" value %s is repeated %d times \n", ep->key, times);
               break;
           }
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: You are misusing `buffer` in your `createHT()` function... while the contents of `buffer` are constantly changing, the value of `buffer` itself is not... so every one of your `e.key` values is identical. That is, when you create the second entry for `i==1`, the string pointed to by the previous `e.key` changes. If instead of `e.key = buffer;` you try `e.key = strdup(buffer);` you may see an improvement (if the rest of your code is solid).

Comment: @mah - Sure, will change it - if I do e.key = strdup(buffer); I wont need to do free memory since I am doing hdestroy(); or do I need to ?

Comment: It looks like you not only don't have to free it yourself, but that previously you would have indirectly caused a crash when calling hdestroy(): _The hdestroy() function calls free(3) for each comparison
     key in the search table but not the data item associated with the key._

Comment: Note that `<search.h>` is not defined by the C standard.  It is part of POSIX, though.

Comment: @mah - Actually I didnt see crash with non-usage of strdup. However if I use strdup I do see memory leak through valgrind. sorry for my confusion but I am going to use strdup to assign value to key only - Now from what you said "The hdestroy() function calls free(3) for each comparison key in the search table but not the data item associated with the key" - shouldnt the memory allocated through strdup be taken care of in that case ?  I tried to manually free it but that's causing the crash :)

Comment: @mah - My understanding is if I use e.key = strdup(buffer); e.key would have the pointer to allocated memory - and now to retrieve for freeing the memory I am doing search again - getting pointer to key and freeing the memory , but seems that is incorrect - Can you please guide me how to approach this ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for the info

Comment: Your code seems to look for numbers which exist `REPEAT` (3) times in the input.  But the problem statement says "Find the n most frequent element in an array."  These don't seem to be the same problem...so are you sure you're solving the right problem with this code?

Comment: @JohnZwinck - Sorry for the confusion - I meant to say for given n - so I took example of 3 - it could be 2-- 10 or any number x .. that's what I was trying to suggest

Comment: @oneday my understanding from the documentation is that as long as you've given `e` to the hashmap with an `ENTER`, `e.key` not yours to `free()` anymore. Rather, in order to free it you _must_ call `hdestroy()` and in fact if you were to free it, a future call to `hdestroy()` or `hsearch()` would result in undefined behavior due to attempting to free an already freed buffer or accessing content of a freed buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd use the [`hcreate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hcreate.html), `hsearch()`, `hdestroy()` triad of functions for this task, but it can be used.  The POSIX specification is not clear on some issues, such as the release of the keys by `htdestroy()`, but the Mac OS X manual says:

> The `hdestroy()` function disposes of the search table, and may be followed by another call to `hcreate()`.  After the call to `hdestroy()`, the data can no longer be considered accessible.  The `hdestroy()` function calls `free(3)` for each comparison key in the search table but not the data item associated with the key.

(POSIX doesn't mention `hdestroy()` calling `free()` on the comparison keys.)

Here's a relatively simple adaptation of your code that works and runs cleanly under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org), at least with GCC 6.1.0 and Valgrind 3.12.0-SVN on Mac OS X 10.11.4.

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror hs17.c -o hs17
$
```

#### Code

```
#include <search.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10

void freqElement(int *arr, int len, int times);
int createHT(int *arr, int len);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 10, 2, 5, 2, 8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, };
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);

    if (hcreate(len) == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create hash table of size %d\n", len);
    else
    {
        if (!createHT(arr, len))
            fprintf(stderr, "error in entering data\n");
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
                freqElement(arr, len, i);
        }

        hdestroy();
    }
    return 0;
}

int createHT(int *arr, int len)
{
    ENTRY e, *ep;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", arr[i]);
        e.key = strdup(buffer);
        e.data = (void *)0;
        printf("Processing [%s]\n", e.key);

        ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);
        if (ep)
        {
            ep->data = (void *)((intptr_t)ep->data + 1);
            if (ep->key != e.key)
                free(e.key);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "entry failed for [%s]\n", e.key);
            free(e.key);    // Not dreadfully important
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// Check whether this number has been processed before
static bool processed_before(int *arr, int len, int value)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        if (value == arr[j])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void freqElement(int *arr, int len, int times)
{
    ENTRY *ep, e;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        snprintf(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "%d", arr[i]);
        e.key = buffer;
        ep = hsearch(e, FIND);
        if (ep)
        {
            if ((intptr_t)ep->data == times && !processed_before(arr, i, arr[i]))
                printf(" value %s is repeated %d times\n", ep->key, times);
        }
    }
}
```

The `processed_before()` function prevents values with multiple entries being printed multiple times — it's a consequence of the change to the `freqElement()` function that reports on all the entries with the given number of appearances, rather than just the first such entry.  It isn't entirely desirable, but the   The code includes some printing so that the progress can be monitored, which helps reassure that the code is working correctly.

#### Example output

```
Processing [2]
Processing [3]
Processing [5]
Processing [6]
Processing [10]
Processing [10]
Processing [2]
Processing [5]
Processing [2]
Processing [8]
Processing [8]
Processing [7]
Processing [8]
Processing [7]
Processing [8]
Processing [7]
 value 3 is repeated 1 times 
 value 6 is repeated 1 times 
 value 5 is repeated 2 times 
 value 10 is repeated 2 times 
 value 2 is repeated 3 times 
 value 7 is repeated 3 times 
 value 8 is repeated 4 times
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ran your code with valgrind-3.7.0 and I am seeing kind of same memory leak that I see with my code ==12296== 
==12296== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12296==     in use at exit: 15 bytes in 7 blocks
==12296==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 10 frees, 250 bytes allocated
==12296== Searching for pointers to 7 not-freed blocks
==12296== Checked 56,876 bytes
==12296== 15 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==12296==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==12296==    by 0x40C2D60: strdup (strdup.c:43)

Comment: Which platform are you running on?  It sounds as if the `hdestroy()` on your system doesn't call `free()` on the keys. Does the man page say that it does?

Comment: It would also be accurate to say that the more I look at the specification of these functions, the less I like them. The POSIX spec is minimal; there's no provision for multiple hash tables; there's no way to iterate over the keys; there isn't an"apply" mechanism; it isn't clear how you're supposed to handle allocated data pointers.  It all adds up to "do not use unless forced to do so".

Comment: I am running it on Ubuntu 12.x . I also understand your point regarding avoiding usage of these library functions. Can you please suggest which are ideal library functions to use for hashtable, so that I dont change wrong goose. As I said I am self learning this aspects so not aware of commonly used library function for such practice

Comment: Getting towards time to uprade, I believe; 16.04 is out and will become the next LTE version shortly.  Anyway, I'm not aware of a specific good alternative to use. You can look at what's available in GLIBC; there's almost bound to be something more appropriate. You could look at the code from Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](https://cii.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install.html) — there's a [book](http://www.amazon.com/Interfaces-Implementations-Techniques-Creating-Reusable/dp/0201498413) too. If you use C++, there are facilities in the standard library (C++11, C++14 — unordered maps).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the problem statement, since as I mentioned in a comment I don't think your current code addresses the problem:

> Find the n most frequent element in an array.
>
> 1 < N < 100000 [Length of Array]
>
> -1000000 < n < 1000000 [Array integers]

I take this to mean we want a function like this:

```
size_t n_most_popular(int input[], size_t input_size, int output[], size_t output_size);
```

This function takes the input array (of size up to 100000) of integers (between -1000000 and 1000000), and populates the output array with the N most common elements from the input, where N is `output_size`.  For convenience we can stipulate that we will place the most common element at the front of the output, and less common elements toward the back.

A straightforward approach to this would be to first sort the input array (possibly in place, possibly using standard `qsort()`).  Then you'll have an array like this:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,7,...]
```

Then, make an array of structs where each struct contains a unique value from the input, plus the number of times it occurs.  Maximum length of this is `input_size`, and it's trivial to build it in a single pass from the sorted input.

Finally, sort this array of structs by the count field in descending order, using standard `qsort()`.  Copy the first `output_size` elements to the output array, and return the actual populated size of the output array (which may be smaller than `output_size` if there are not enough unique values in the input array).

Here's a working C program to do just that:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t most_popular(int input[], size_t input_size, int output[], size_t output_size);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 10, 2, 5, 2};
    size_t len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

    int out[3];
    size_t outlen = sizeof(out)/sizeof(int);

    size_t count = most_popular(arr, len, out, outlen);

    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < count; ii++) {
        printf("most popular rank %lu: %d\n", ii+1, out[ii]);
    }

    return 0;
}

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    int count;
} value_count;

int value_count_greater(const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    const value_count *vcl = lhs, *vcr = rhs;
    return vcr->count - vcl->count;
}

int int_less(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    const int *il = lhs, *ir = rhs;
    return *il - *ir;
}

// returns 0 if out of memory or input_size is 0, else returns valid portion of output                                                                                    
size_t most_popular(int input[], size_t input_size, int output[], size_t output_size)
{
    qsort(input, input_size, sizeof(input[0]), int_less);

    value_count* value_counts = malloc(input_size * sizeof(value_count));
    if (value_counts == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    // count how many times each value occurs in input                                                                                                                    
    size_t unique_count = 0;
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < input_size; ii++) {
        if (ii == 0 || input[ii] != value_counts[unique_count-1].value) {
            value_counts[unique_count].value = input[ii];
            value_counts[unique_count].count = 1;
            unique_count++;
        } else {
            value_counts[unique_count-1].count++;
        }
    }

    // sort unique values by how often they occur, most popular first                                                                                                     
    qsort(value_counts, unique_count, sizeof(value_counts[0]), value_count_greater);

    size_t result_size = unique_count < output_size ? unique_count : output_size;
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < result_size; ii++) {
        output[ii] = value_counts[ii].value;
    }

    free(value_counts);
    return result_size;
}
```